# RxSwift observe array change only when appended new element

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift

Is there a way to subscribe to array change only when a new element is appended?

So I want the following closure to be executed only when a new element is appended.

```
array.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: { array in

}).disposed(by: self.bag)
```

If, for example, an element is removed from this array, I don't want this closure to be executed.

**EDIT:**

Is there a way to only have newly appended elements in the closure? In my case I append subsequences of various lengths, so I can't just look at the last element of the array inside the closure.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe something like this

```
 let array = Variable<[Int]>([])
        array.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged { $0.count > $1.count}.subscribe(onNext: {
            print($0)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)

        array.value.append(1) //called
        array.value.append(2) //called
        array.value.remove(at: 0) //not called
        array.value.append(3) //called
```

Comment: Variable is deprecated better to use BehaviorRelay

Comment: This is the correct answer; but, is there a way to only have newly appended elements in the closure? In my case I append subsequences of various lengths, so I can't just look at the last element of the array inside the closure.

Comment: you mean using filter? can you show example of your array?

Comment: For example. var array = [0,1,2]; then i do this: array.append([3,4,5]). How can i get only the newly appended subsequence in the subscription closure i.e. [3,4,5]

Answer (score 0):

In that case you should resign using Variable and use Subjects. I think, that your requirements should meet PublishSubject:

```
let subjectArray = PublishSubject<[Int]>([])
array.asObservable().subscribe(onNext: {
            print($0)
        }).disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

When you add new elements to subjectArray only that new elements will be printed.